# Calculate a running total during a for loop - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, cumulative-sum

**Edit: Below is my working code based on the feedback/answers I recieved.**

This question stems from my previous question that came up while learning Python/CS using open courseware from MIT. --[See my previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990159/python-beginner-is-this-python-code-as-efficient-as-it-could-be)--

I am using the following code to make a list of month payments and other things. However at the end of the loop I need to give a running total for the total amount that has been paid of the months.

**Original Code**

```
balance = float(raw_input("Outstanding Balance: "))
interestRate = float(raw_input("Interest Rate: "))
minPayRate = float(raw_input("Minimum Monthly Payment Rate: "))

for month in xrange(1, 12+1):
    interestPaid = round(interestRate / 12.0 * balance, 2)
    minPayment = round(minPayRate * balance, 2)
    principalPaid = round(minPayment - interestPaid, 2)
    remainingBalance = round(balance - principalPaid, 2)


    print 'Month: %d' % (month,)
    print 'Minimum monthly payment: %.2f' % (minPayment,)
    print 'Principle paid: %.2f' % (principalPaid,)
    print 'Remaining balance: %.2f' % (remainingBalance,)

    balance = remainingBalance

    if month in xrange(12, 12+1):
        print 'RESULTS'
        print 'Total amount paid: '
        print 'Remaining balance: %.2f' % (remainingBalance,)
```

The problem is that I have not been able to figure out how to keep a running total of the amounts paid. I tried adding `totalPaid = round(interestPaid + principalPaid, 2)` but that just led to a total for a single month, I cant seem to get it to keep that value for each month and then add them all up at the end to be printed out.

Also I know that the resulting amount should be 1131.12

I have found many examples of doing this when each value is know, via a list, but I cant seem to extrapolate that correctly.

**Fixed Code**

```
balance = float(raw_input("Outstanding Balance: "))
interestRate = float(raw_input("Interest Rate: "))
minPayRate = float(raw_input("Minimum Monthly Payment Rate: "))
totalPaid = 0

for month in xrange(1, 12+1):
    interestPaid = round(interestRate / 12.0 * balance, 2)
    minPayment = round(minPayRate * balance, 2)
    principalPaid = round(minPayment - interestPaid, 2)
    remainingBalance = round(balance - principalPaid, 2)
    totalPaid += round(minPayment, 2)

    print 'Month: %d' % (month,)
    print 'Minimum monthly payment: %.2f' % (minPayment,)
    print 'Principle paid: %.2f' % (principalPaid,)
    print 'Remaining balance: %.2f' % (remainingBalance,)

    balance = remainingBalance

    if month in xrange(12, 12+1):
        print 'RESULTS'
        print 'Total amount paid: %.2f' % (totalPaid,)
        print 'Remaining balance: %.2f' % (remainingBalance,)
```

Comment: Why aren't you **updating** `totalPaid`?  Why do you set it to a new value?  Why not include `totalPaid` in an expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before your loop, initialize a variable to accumulate value:

```
total_paid = 0
```

And then, in the body of your loop, add the appropriate amount to it. You can use the `+=` operator to add to an existing variable, e.g.

```
total_paid += 1
```

is a short form for `total_paid = total_paid + 1`. You don't want to give `total_paid` a new value each iteration, rather you want to add to its existing value.

I'm not sure about the specifics of your problem, but this is the general form for accumulating a value as you loop.

Comment: Thank you for making this more clear to me. I was able to extrapolate what you said and added the `totalPaid = 0` before the loop and within the loop I added `totalPaid += round(minPayment, 2)`

Comment: @tehaaron no problem, always happy to help someone learning Python

Answer (score 1):

You always make the minimum payment?  Just use minPayment instead of figuring out that math again.  Keep a running total, then print it out *after* the loop.

```
balance = float(raw_input("Outstanding Balance: "))
interestRate = float(raw_input("Interest Rate: "))
minPayRate = float(raw_input("Minimum Monthly Payment Rate: "))
paid = 0

for month in xrange(1, 12+1):
    interestPaid = round(interestRate / 12.0 * balance, 2)
    minPayment = round(minPayRate * balance, 2)
    principalPaid = round(minPayment - interestPaid, 2)
    remainingBalance = round(balance - principalPaid, 2)
    paid += minPayment

    print  # Make the output easier to read.
    print 'Month: %d' % (month,)
    print 'Minimum monthly payment: %.2f' % (minPayment,)
    print 'Principle paid: %.2f' % (principalPaid,)
    print 'Remaining balance: %.2f' % (remainingBalance,)

    balance = remainingBalance

print
print 'RESULTS'
print 'Total amount paid:', paid
print 'Remaining balance: %.2f' % (remainingBalance,)
```

Also notice that range has exactly one value, so you'd just check month == 12, but it's simply not necessary here.

Comment: Thanks this is basically exactly what I did, but I got to it after reading Rafe's answer, so I gave it to him. :) I appreciate the quick response after commenting you on my previous question.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856727/7847222) worked for me:

First, create the derived value:

```
df.loc[0, 'C'] = df.loc[0, 'D']
```

Then iterate through the remaining rows and fill the calculated values:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'C'] = df.loc[i-1, 'C'] * df.loc[i, 'A'] + df.loc[i, 'B']
```

| Index_Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015/01/31 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2015/02/01 | 2 | 3 | 23 | 22 |
| 2015/02/02 | 10 | 60 | 290 | 280 |

Comment: edit your answer in order to be readable (as a code).

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to initialize totalPaid to 0 and then

```
totalPaid = round(interestPaid + principalPaid, 2) + totalPaid
```

Inside the loop. Your problem is that you're not accumulating the total, you're just setting a new one on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you were close. The problem is that you were overwriting the total each time. Try something like this:

```
totalPaid = totalPaid + round(interestPaid + principalPaid, 2)
```