# Is there a way in Pandas to use previous row values in dataframe.apply where previous values are also calculated in the apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
      W    Y
 0    1    5
 1    2    NaN
 2    3    NaN
 3    4    NaN
 4    5    NaN
 5    6    NaN
 6    7    NaN
 ...
```

as the table rows keeps going until index 240. I want to get the following dataframe:

```
      W    Y
 0    1    5
 1    2    7
 2    3    10
 3    4    14
 4    5    19
 5    6    27
 6    7    37
 ...
```

Please note that the values of `W` are arbitrary (just to make the computation here easier, in fact they are `np.random.normal` in my real program).
Or in other words:
If Y index is 0, then the value of Y is 5;
If Y index is between 1 and 4 (includes) then Y_i is the sum of the previous element in Y and the current elemnt in W.
If Y index is >=5 then the value of Y is: Y_{i-1} + Y_{i-4} - Y_{i-5} + W_i

using [iipr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855859/is-there-a-way-in-pandas-to-use-previous-row-value-in-dataframe-apply-when-previ) answer I've managed to compute the first five values by running:

```
def calculate(add):
    global value
    value = value + add
    return value

df.Y = np.nan
value = 5
df.loc[0, 'Y'] = value
df.loc[1:5, 'Y'] = df.loc[1:5].apply(lambda row: calculate(*row[['W']]), axis=1)
```

but I haven't managed to compute the rest of values (where index>=5).
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `If Y index is >=5 then the value of Y is: Y_i + Y_{i-4} - Y_{i-5} + W_i`. What is `Y_i`
 here? Shouldn't it be a NaN

Comment: Sorry, my bad, suppose to be Y_{i-1}, I'm editing my question

Comment: `Y_6=Y_5+Y_2-Y_1+W_6=27+10-7+7=37`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to use `apply` in this case.
Why not simply use two loops, for each differently defined range one:

```
for i in df.index[1:5]:
    df.loc[i, 'Y'] = df.W.loc[i] + df.Y.loc[i-1]
for i in df.index[5:]:
    df.loc[i, 'Y'] = df.W.loc[i] + df.Y.loc[i-1] + df.Y.loc[i-4] - df.Y.loc[i-5]
```

This is straight forward and you still know next week what the code does.