# Calculate cumulative column with calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
data = {'month': {0: Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2019-02-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00')},
 'base_expenses': {0: 200.0, 1: 200.0, 2: 200.0, 3: 200.0, 4: 200.0},
 'base_contribution': {0: 100.0, 1: 100.0, 2: 100.0, 3: 100.0, 4: 100.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

month   base_expenses   base_contribution
0   2019-01-01  200.0   100.0
1   2019-02-01  200.0   100.0
2   2019-03-01  200.0   100.0
3   2019-04-01  200.0   100.0
4   2019-05-01  200.0   100.0
```

This data will represent an investment which has additional contributions added to it every month and which grows by a certain percentage every month.

So for example the starting balance of the investment is `50000`. Every month we add `base_contribution` to the balance. Lastly, every month the balance grows by `0.6%`.

I can calculate all this using a loop as follows:

```py
CURRENT_BALANCE = 50000
MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN = 0.006

df['base_balance'] = CURRENT_BALANCE
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        balance = row['base_contribution'] + row['base_balance']
        balance += balance * MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN
        df.loc[row.name, 'base_balance'] = balance
    else:
        balance = row['base_contribution'] + df.loc[row.name - 1, 'base_balance']
        balance += balance * MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN
        df.loc[row.name, 'base_balance'] = balance
```

The result would be:

```py
    month   base_expenses   base_contribution   base_balance
0   2019-01-01  200.0   100.0   50422.344909
1   2019-02-01  200.0   100.0   50847.407197
2   2019-03-01  200.0   100.0   51275.204349
3   2019-04-01  200.0   100.0   51705.753960
4   2019-05-01  200.0   100.0   52139.073741
```

The real data that I am working with is very large and so I would prefer to avoid this looping approach if possible. Is there a way to do this in a vectorised manor or without looping?

Comment: According to your code, for the first line I get : (50000+100)*1.006 = 50400.6 .  
So I don't understand how you get 50422.344909.

Comment: probably write the code in numpy and use numba to speed it up

Comment: @IsmaelELATIFI that is because I rounded MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN to 3 decimal points for the sake of simplicity. The actual number is 0.00643403011000343. My apologies for the confusion however the core of the question remains.

Comment: Ok I see. By the way there is no point in vectorizing here because your calculations are sequential i.e. you need to compute for row N to be able to compute for row N+1. So because it cannot be parrallelized this is not something worth to vectorize.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense, good point. Thanks.

Comment: Is the base_contribution constant or can it vary. If constant, the way can be shorter than the loop, calculating the return of the money of the first month and then use cumsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855859/is-there-a-way-in-pandas-to-use-previous-row-value-in-dataframe-apply-when-previ), it seems it's not feasible

You can save an `if` in each loop. And `df.at` is also a speeder way to set a value in a dataframe.

```
balance = df.loc[0, 'base_contribution'] + df.loc[0, 'base_balance']
balance += balance * MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN
df.at[0, 'base_balance'] = balance

for index, row in df[1:].iterrows():
    balance = row['base_contribution'] + df.loc[row.name - 1, 'base_balance']
    balance += balance * MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN
    df.at[index, 'base_balance'] = balance
```

I've found interesting methods : `rolling`, `cumsum` and `expanding`. But nothing works here, due to the fact that we do not know the values of base_contribution on start.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the base_balance is constant.

With one intermediate step you can do what you want:
Keep in mind that you can split the investment in parts and calculate the return on each part.

So the resulting value of the starting balance (CURRENT_BALANCE ) at the time of the nth month can be written as:

```
df["result_on_start_investment"] =  CURRENT_BALANCE * math.pow(MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN,  np.arange(len(df)) + 1)
```

Each month an additional amount is added to the investment. This amount gets its return every month. As a first step calculate

```
df["result_on_added_at_month_one"] = base_balance * math.pow(MONTHLY_INVESTMENT_RETURN,  np.arange(len(df)) + 1)
```

and finally as the revenue of added money at month n-1 is equal to the revenue of money added at month 1 at month 2:

```
df["balance"] = df["result_on_start_investment"] + df["result_on_added_at_month_one"].cumsum()
```

Result:

```
month  base_expenses  base_contribution  n  result_on_added_at_month_one  result_on_start_investment       balance
0      0          200.0              100.0  1                    100.643403                50321.701506  50422.344909
1      1          200.0              100.0  2                    101.290946                50645.472848  50847.407197
2      2          200.0              100.0  3                    101.942655                50971.327345  51275.204349
3      3          200.0              100.0  4                    102.598557                51299.278400  51705.753960
4      4          200.0              100.0  5                    103.258679                51629.339502  52139.073741
```