# Create a Pandas colun that refers to its values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert VBA macro to python script. I need to add a new column to dataframe:

```
 X  Y 
    
 1  2 
 3  4
 5  6 
 7  8
```

that will be a sum of a value above (0 for the first one) and value from X multiplied by Y summed with a value above :

```
 X  Y  Z    Z(calculations) 

 1  2  0    0 
 3  4  12   0 + 3*(4+0)
 5  6  102  12 + 5*(6+12)  
 7  8  872  102 + 7*(8+102)
```

So basically Excel formula (in Z2 Cell):

```
=Z1+X2*(Y2+Z1)
```

Is there an easy (and quick) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a for loop but since you asked for a quick way you can do this using numba and @njit:

```
from numba import njit

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@njit
def calculate(X, Y):
    res = np.empty(X.shape)
    res[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, res.shape[0]):
        res[i] = res[i-1] + (X[i] * (Y[i] + res[i-1]))
    return res

df = pd.DataFrame({"X": [1,3,5,7], "Y": [2,4,6,8]})
df
   X  Y
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8

df["Z"] = calculator_nb(*df[["X", "Y"]].values.T)

df
   X  Y      Z
0  1  2    0.0
1  3  4   12.0
2  5  6  102.0
3  7  8  872.0
```

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855859/is-there-a-way-in-pandas-to-use-previous-row-value-in-dataframe-apply-when-previ)