# Replace the value if isnumeric is equal to False - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I display the actual value of column if the result of the `isnumeric` = `False` and `fill` the `NaN` based on the `SKU`

**DF**

```
      SKU    SKU2
  SKU_ABC    False
        0    NaN
        0    NaN
        0    NaN
  SKU_ACD    False
        0    NaN
        0    NaN
```

**Expected result**

```
      SKU    SKU2
  SKU_ABC    SKU_ABC
        0    SKU_ABC
        0    SKU_ABC
        0    SKU_ABC
  SKU_ACD    SKU_ACD
        0    SKU_ACD
        0    SKU_ACD
```

**Script (only displayed True/False)**

```
df2['SKU2'] = df2['SKU'].str.isnumeric()
```

I tried this one

```
df2['SKU2'] = df[~df2['SKU'].str.isnumeric()]
```

but I got this error

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this solution [Is there a way in Pandas to use previous row value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856727/9350669)

with for loop:

```
df['SKU'] = df['SKU'].fillna('0')
df['SKU2'] = df['SKU'].astype(str).str.isnumeric().fillna(False)
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'SKU2']:
        df.loc[i, 'SKU2'] = df.loc[i-1, 'SKU2']
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'SKU2'] = df.loc[i, 'SKU']
```

as I understand the problem here is the `isnumeric` so let's try to bypass it with other options
with np.where: `df['SKU'].str.contains('SKU')`

```
df['SKU2'] = np.where(df['SKU'].astype(str).fillna('0').str.contains('SKU'),df.SKU, None) 
df['SKU2'] = df['SKU2'].ffill()
```

if it's always '0':`df['SKU']=='0'`

```
df['SKU2'] = np.where(df['SKU'].astype(str).fillna('0')=='0', None,df.SKU)
df['SKU2'] = df['SKU2'].ffill()
```