# Calculating index values based on previous calculations using the same calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`:

```
pd.DataFrame(index = ['A','B','C'],
             columns = ['1','2','3','4'], 
             data = [[100,60,40,60],
                     [200,10,50,80],
                     [50, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])
```

```
        1           2           3           4        
A       100         60          40          60
B       200         10          50          80
C       50
```

I would like to calculate the remaining `C` index values, but each calculation is dependent on the previous value like so:

```
        1           2           3           4        
A       100         60          40          60
B       200         10          50          80
C       50          A2+B2-C1    A3+B3-C2    A4+B4-C3
```

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855859/is-there-a-way-in-pandas-to-use-previous-row-value-in-dataframe-apply-when-previ) and tried the following:

```
new = [df.loc['C'].values]

for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    new.append(new[i-1]*df.loc['A'].values[i]+df.loc['B'].values[i]-df.loc['C'].values[i-1])
df.loc['C'] = new
```

But I get :

> ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Also, the question and answers are quite outdated, maybe there is a new solution for these recursive functions inside pandas dataframe?

Comment: can you share a `df.to_dict()` ? So we can understand the exact structure of the Datafrme

Comment: why `new[i-1]*` ?

Comment: Added `df` creation. `[i-1]` to use the previous column for `C`?

Comment: Perfromance is important? then use `numba`. If not, use loop solutions similar like accepted linked solution.

Comment: Performance is not important, I tried using the loop solution in the accepted answer but did not work as expected because of me having indexes while the answer uses column structure.

Comment: I don't see any multiplication in the schema above, so why do I see one in the code ?

Answer (score 2):

Key is : print your variables to ensure they contains what you think

---

- First is that `new = [df.loc['C'].values]` builds a list with one item being an array, you just want one list
- Then if the loop you're using `new[i-1] *`, which isn't present in the schema above
- you use `df.loc['C'].values[i-1]` but you don't update it (you save in  a list) so you can't expect it to work

  - directly update the DF and use `- df.loc['C'].values[i-1]`
  - keep the temporaty list and use `- new[i - 1]`
- you don't want to append, but overwrite the values (or you'd have need to start `new` with only one value

---

With a separate list

```
new = df.loc['C'].to_list()

for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    new[i] = df.loc['A'].values[i] + df.loc['B'].values[i] - new[i - 1]
```

---

Without a separate list

```
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[2, i] = df.iloc[1, i] + df.iloc[0, i] - df.iloc[2, i - 1]
```

Comment: What happens if instead of columns being `1,2...` I have `2021-11-29, 2021-12-06 ...`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis the code doesn't use the column name at all, it shouldn't cause trouble. Also can't you just try and answer that question by yourself ? ;)