# Use previous row value to calculate next value in Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, iteration, multi-index

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856727) SO answer comes close to what I am looking for, but I cannot apply it to a MultiIndex `DataFrame`.

I define a hierarchically-indexed `Dataframe` like this:

```
arrays = [["bar", "bar"], ["one", "two"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=["A", "B", "C", "D"], columns=index)
```

Output:

```
first        bar             foo
second       one       two   one
A       1.764052  0.400157  None
B       0.978738  2.240893  None
C       1.867558 -0.977278  None
D       0.950088 -0.151357  None
```

I want to populate a new df['foo', 'one'] column as follows:

- I want the first row n to be 100.
- I want row n+1 to be: n * (df['bar', 'one'][n] + 1)
- And so on.

The final table should look like:

```
first        bar             foo
second       one       two   one
A       1.764052  0.400157  100
B       0.978738  2.240893  276.4
C       1.867558 -0.977278  546.9
D       0.950088 -0.151357  1568.4
```

The main issue I am facing is accessing the row idx of a MultiIndex `DataFrame`. `df['foo', 'one'][0]=100` works but throws a warning: `"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"`.

And `df.loc[0, 'bar', 'one']` throws `"Too many indexers"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you want is a [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) where you initialize the value to 100. The rest is just indexing:

```
START = 100
df[('foo', 'one')] = (df[('bar', 'one')]
                      .add(1)
                      .shift(fill_value=START)
                      .cumprod()
                      )
```

output:

```
first        bar                    foo
second       one       two          one
A       1.764052  0.400157   100.000000
B       0.978738  2.240893   276.405235
C       1.867558 -0.977278   546.933537
D       0.950088 -0.151357  1568.363633
```

###### indexing

Independently of your goal, to index a MultiIndex you would need to use:

```
df.loc['A', ('bar', 'one')]
```

or, for a mix of names and relative indexing:

```
df[('bar', 'one')].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index doesn't include `0`, also, put the multiindex as a tuple

```
df.loc['A', ('bar', 'one')]
```