# Series Dataframe to List and Keeping Dates

Tags: python, dataframe

This code outputs dates along with values as a series. I wanted to manipulate the values but I ended up losing the dates.

```
rgdp = fred.get_series('GDPC1')
fgdp=rgdp
rlistgdp=[] 
for a in range(len(rgdp)):
    rgdp2=((rgdp.iloc[a]/rgdp.iloc[a-1])**4-1) * 100
    rlistgdp.append(rgdp2)
rlistgdp
```

[Series Dataframe:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN8ug.png)

[Series to List:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fojbC.png)

How can I keep the dates along with the new values?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the dates"? A list of tuples: `[(date, value),...]`? a new series? Please show an example of the expected output.

Comment: I want it to look like the dates from "Series Dataframe", but change the values to "Series to List"

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856727/15032126

Comment: Also, you may want to use `fgdp=rgdp.copy()`, otherwise rgdp is going to be modified when you modify fgdp.

Comment: Avoid using images, except when it's difficult to convey meaning through text. _Write_ examples of the data (not necessary the real data) and the expected output. And write your input data as code, so other people can start just by running it: [mre] and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
series = pd.Series([100,150,200,300], index=['a','b','c','d'])
```

```
series

a    100
b    150
c    200
d    300
dtype: int64
```

```
series2 = series.copy()
for i in range(1, len(series)):
    series2[i] = ((series[i]/series[i-1])**4-1) * 100
```

```
series2

a    100
b    406
c    216
d    406
dtype: int64
```

Notice that I used `copy()` so fgpd doesn't get modified.
The range is set to start in 1 because I don't know how you plan to modify the first value.

Comment: I tried this and Python is returning "TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()"

Comment: Also sorry about the image thing, I'm just new to python so I didn't know how to make the example in code

Comment: I added an example on how to create an example. And tried a slightly different solution, this one works, at least for my example.

Comment: I tried this, but am only returning values for two dates: 

2021-10-01  and 2022-01-01 unfortunately