# Creating New Column in Pandas Using Value from Previous Cell

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to build a cash flow loan model table using Pandas. I've generated several of the fields I need such as Beginning Balance, Interest, Principal, Payment, Ending Balance - as shown below:

| Beginning Balance | Principal | Payment | Interest | Ending Bal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50000.00 | 144.49 | 477.83 | 333.33 | 49855.51 |
| 49855.51 | 145.46 | 477.83 | 332.37 | 49710.05 |
| 49710.05 | 146.43 | 477.83 | 331.40 | 49563.63 |

Now I'm trying to generate new columns using some new data and existing columns such as a Net Outstanding Balance, Prepaid Principal, Charge-Off Principal, and a Scheduled Principle Received:

```
SMM = .0184
Default = .0059
Total_SMM_Loss = .975

cf_table.at[1,'Net Outstanding Balance'] = cf_table.at[1,'Beginning Balance']

cf_table['Scheduled Principle Received'] = cf_table['Principal'] * Total_SMM_Loss

cf_table['Prepaid Principal'] = cf_table['Net Outstanding Balance'] * SMM

cf_table['Charge-Off Principal'] = cf_table['Net Outstanding Balance'] * Default

cf_table.at[2:,'Net Outstanding Balance'] = cf_table['Net Outstanding Balance'] - cf_table['Scheduled Principle Received'] - cf_table['Prepaid Principal'] - cf_table['Charge-Off Principal']
```

For the Net Outstanding Balance column I'm setting the value of the first cell to 50,000 - the beginning balance of the loan. Next I'm creating the other columns, which some rely on the value of the Net Outstanding Balance.

For cell 2 going down in the Net Outstanding Column I'm trying to insert a new formula that will take the previous value of the Net Outstanding Balance into its calculation while subtracting the values from the Prepaid, Charge-Off and Scheduled Principle columns from the previous row into the formula.

However the following table is what I receive below when applying the code above:

| Net Outstanding Balance | Prepaid | Charge-Off | Scheduled Principle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50000.00 | 920.00 | 295.00 | 140.88 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 141.82 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 142.77 |

Comment: Are you looking for [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)?

Comment: `pandas` shines at vectorized operations etc. Your process, as described, sounds very procedural. Usually, these kinds of compound-interest problems can be vectorized by working out the math and express all rows at once with a combination of `cumprod()` and other simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what I was trying to accomplish in the above post. With some help from this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855859/is-there-a-way-in-pandas-to-use-previous-row-value-in-dataframe-apply-when-previ) I was able to put together this code to fill out the rest of this table:

```
cf_table1.loc[1, 'Net Outstanding Balance'] = 50000

for i in range(2, len(cf_table)):
    cf_table1.loc[i, 'Net Outstanding Balance'] = cf_table1.loc[i-1, 'Net Outstanding Balance'] - cf_table1.loc[i, 'Prepaid Principal'] - cf_table1.loc[i, 'Charge-Off Principal'] - cf_table1.loc[i, 'Scheduled Principle Received']
    cf_table1.loc[i-1, 'Prepaid Principal'] = cf_table1.loc[i-1, 'Net Outstanding Balance'] * SMM
    cf_table1.loc[i-1, 'Charge-Off Principal'] = cf_table1.loc[i-1, 'Net Outstanding Balance'] * Default

cf_table1.head(cf_table1. shape[0] -1)
```

| Net Outstanding Balance | Prepaid | Charge-Off | Scheduled Principle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50000.00 | 920.00 | 295.00 | 140.88 |
| 47320.25 | 895.05 | 287.00 | 141.82 |
| 46028.40 | 870.69 | 279.19 | 142.77 |