# Pandas "Formulas" not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, accelerometer

I am trying to work with data from an accelerometer, trying to get the velocity from acceleration, on a df that looks like this:

```
{'T': {0: 0.007719999999999999,
  1: 0.016677999999999797,
  2: 0.024630999999996697,
  3: 0.0325849999999983,
  4: 0.040530999999995196},
 'Ax': {0: 0.16, 1: 0.28, 2: 0.28, 3: 0.44, 4: 0.57},
 'Ay': {0: 8.0, 1: 7.9, 2: 7.87, 3: 7.87, 4: 7.9},
 'Az': {0: 3.83, 1: 3.83, 2: 3.79, 3: 3.76, 4: 3.76},
 'delta T': {0: 0.00772,
  1: 0.008957999999999798,
  2: 0.0079529999999969,
  3: 0.007954000000001606,
  4: 0.007945999999996893}}
```

[example of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svoar.png)

First, I set the Velocity of X, Y and Z to 0:

```
df_yt["Vx"] = 0
df_yt["Vy"] = 0
df_yt["Vz"] = 0
```

And then I entered the first value of each of these columns manually:

```
df_yt.loc[0,"Vx"] = 0.16*0.007720
df_yt.loc[0,"Vy"] = 8.00*0.007720
df_yt.loc[0,"Vz"] = 3.83*0.007720
```

I wanted to create a formula that returned the previous element in Vx + (Ax*delta T) of the same column. And to write the "formulas" of these 3 columns, I assumed it would be something like:

```
df_yt.loc[1:,"Vx"] = df_yt["Vx"].shift(1) + df_yt["Ax"]*df_yt["delta T"]
df_yt.loc[1:,"Vy"] = df_yt["Vy"].shift(1) + df_yt["Ay"]*df_yt["delta T"]
df_yt.loc[1:,"Vz"] = df_yt["Vz"].shift(1) + df_yt["Az"]*df_yt["delta T"]
```

and this code doesn't return any error but the numbers on the df don't match what they should, for example:

[This number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2Gc.png)

should be 0.005970:

```
0.003743 + 0.28*0.007953 = 0.005970
```

I hope someone can help me with this because I don't know what is causing this mistake and I can't even understand where the wrong numbers are coming from.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample from the `df` as text, not as a picture. E.g. use `df.to_dict()` or `df.head().to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). This makes it much easier for other users to reproduce your issue and to try to provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as follows:

- Use [`df.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) to multiply each column in `['Ax','Ay','Az']` with `delta T` along axis `0`, and apply [`df.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

```
df_yt[['Vx','Vy','Vz']] = df_yt[['Ax','Ay','Az']].mul(df_yt['delta T'], 
                                                      axis=0).cumsum()

print(df_yt)

          T    Ax    Ay    Az   delta T        Vx        Vy        Vz
0  0.007720  0.16  8.00  3.83  0.007720  0.001235  0.061760  0.029568
1  0.016678  0.28  7.90  3.83  0.008958  0.003743  0.132528  0.063877
2  0.024631  0.28  7.87  3.79  0.007953  0.005970  0.195118  0.094019
3  0.032585  0.44  7.87  3.76  0.007954  0.009470  0.257716  0.123926
4  0.040531  0.57  7.90  3.76  0.007946  0.013999  0.320490  0.153803
```

Incidentally, the problem with your own attempt becomes apparent when you print the values for any of the `.shift(1)` statements. E.g. you do:

```
df_yt["Vx"] = 0
df_yt.loc[0,"Vx"] = 0.16*0.007720

print(df_yt["Vx"].shift(1))

0         NaN
1    0.001235
2    0.000000
3    0.000000
4    0.000000
Name: Vx, dtype: float64
```

So, in a line such as `df_yt.loc[1:,"Vx"] = df_yt["Vx"].shift(1) + df_yt["Ax"]*df_yt["delta T"]`, per row you are adding: nothing (`NaN`), `0.001235`, and then just *zeros* after that. E.g. this adds correct values only for the second row (index `1`).

Comment: You're right, and your code worked perfectly, I don't know how it worked without referencing the previous value of Vx, Vy and Vz, but it's returning the correct values

Comment: "I don't know how it worked without referencing the previous value of Vx, Vy and Vz". This is what `.cumsum()` is doing: it "[r]eturn[s] cumulative sum over a DataFrame or Series axis". E.g., for `Ax` we are first getting the multipled values: `[0.001235, 0.002508, 0.002227, 0.0035, 0.004529]` (rounded here) and `cumsum` then turns this into `[0.001235, 0.003743, 0.00597, 0.00947, 0.013999]`, i.e. `[0.001235, 0.002508 + 0.001235, 0.002227 + 0.002508 + 0.001235, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are vectorized and not iterative and therefore the relations between the rows are not based on the previous calculations.

For the input:

```
       T      Ax         Ay      Az      delta T           Vx     Vy       Vz
0   0.007720    0.16    8.00    3.83    0.007720    0.001235    0.06176 0.029568
1   0.016678    0.28    7.90    3.83    0.008958    0.000000    0.00000 0.000000
2   0.024631    0.28    7.87    3.79    0.007953    0.000000    0.00000 0.000000
3   0.032585    0.44    7.87    3.76    0.007954    0.000000    0.00000 0.000000
4   0.040531    0.57    7.90    3.76    0.007946    0.000000    0.00000 0.000000
```

If you would run `df_yt["Vx"].shift(1)`, you will get:

```
0         NaN
1    0.001235
2    0.000000
3    0.000000
4    0.000000
```

Therefore you calculation for Vx, is actually:

[image]

Based on the post here: [Is there a way in Pandas to use previous row value in dataframe.apply when previous value is also calculated in the apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855859/is-there-a-way-in-pandas-to-use-previous-row-value-in-dataframe-apply-when-previ)

Based on the post above,
I would suggest:

```
for i in range(1, len(df_yt)):
    df_yt.loc[i, 'Vx'] = df_yt.loc[i-1, 'Vx'] + df_yt.loc[i, 'Ax']*df_yt.loc[i, 'delta T']
    df_yt.loc[i, 'Vy'] = df_yt.loc[i-1, 'Vy'] + df_yt.loc[i, 'Ay']*df_yt.loc[i, 'delta T']
    df_yt.loc[i, 'Vz'] = df_yt.loc[i-1, 'Vz'] + df_yt.loc[i, 'Az']*df_yt.loc[i, 'delta T']
```

Output:

```
       T         Ax      Ay      Az      delta T      Vx           Vy    Vz
0   0.007720    0.16    8.00    3.83    0.007720    0.001235    0.061760    0.029568
1   0.016678    0.28    7.90    3.83    0.008958    0.003743    0.132528    0.063877
2   0.024631    0.28    7.87    3.79    0.007953    0.005970    0.195118    0.094019
3   0.032585    0.44    7.87    3.76    0.007954    0.009470    0.257716    0.123926
4   0.040531    0.57    7.90    3.76    0.007946    0.013999    0.320490    0.153803
```

- I know it's not vectorize

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello, I tried that and I got a MemoryError after waiting for 30 minutes for it to run ahahah  because this df has more than a million of rows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74020604/adding-values-in-a-column-by-formula-in-a-pandas-dataframe/74020773?noredirect=1#comment130696859_74020773